How can I jump to the parent node of a JSON object in Notepad++?
Let's say my cursor in Notepad++ is here:

How can I easily jump to the parent node? E.g., is there a keyboard shortcut for that?

Full JSON used in the example:
{
    "boats": [
        {
            "id": "Bobboat",
            "labels": [
                {
                    "minSpeed": "200",
                    "maxSpeed": "302",
                    "boat": [
                        "h boat"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "boat",
            "boatbar": true
        },
        {
            "id": "pencilboat",
            "labels": [
                {
                    "minSpeed": "201",
                    "maxSpeed": "230",
                    "boat": [
                        "Penny boat"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "boat",
            "boatbar": true
        },
        {
            "id": "coboat",
            "labels": [
                {
                    "minSpeed": "229",
                    "maxSpeed": "255",
                    "boat": [
                        "Colin boat"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "boat",
            "boatbar": true
        }
    }
}


Have you tried JSON Tools plugin?
